# What are the different types of currency?

Tags: h1z1-king-of-the-kill

I notice four types of currency on the home-screen.  How do I get them?  What can I use them each for?

Comment: I haven't played h1z1 but are the currencies you are seeing referenced here? 
https://www.h1z1.com/king-of-the-kill/news/crowns-keys-crates-airdrop-tickets-change-september-2016